# Labeling with expressions in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling

Some polygons in my map have a "name" (but no "capacity") and some have a "capacity" (but no "name") and some have both.

I want to label the polygons with the "name" and the "capacity". Therefore I use the following string:

```
"name" || '\n' || "capacity"
```

But this does not work.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

I'm so stupid... I've got an solution that works fine:

CASE WHEN "name" is NULL THEN '' ELSE "name" END 
||   '\n'  || 
CASE WHEN "capacity" is NULL THEN '' ELSE ("capacity" ) END

Answer (score 1):

in this case using the 'coalesce function'

`coalesce( "name", ' ') ||'\n'|| coalesce( "capacity" ,' ')`

Returns the first non-NULL value from the expression list.
This function can take any number of arguments.